# Sum function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
 PropertyID     Amount        
 --------------------------
   1              40                   
   1              20                
   1              10                    
   2              10                 
   2              90
```

I would like to achieve :

```
    PropertyId       Amount   Total_Amount
  ---------------------------------------       
      1                40        70
      1                20        70
      1                10        70
      2                10        100
      2                90        100
```

using below query :

```
SELECT  
    PropertyID,
    SUM(Amount),
    SUM(TotalAmount)
FROM 
    yourTable
WHERE 
    EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    PropertyID
```

Output:

```
    PropertyId       Amount   TotalAmount
  -------------------------------------       
      1                70      70
      2                100     100
```

Let me know how can I get my desired output ...

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select PropertyID, Amount,
       sum(Amount) over (partition by PropertyId) as TotalAmount
from yourtable;
```

The window function for `sum()` does the following.  It calculates the sum of `amount` for groups of rows in the same group.  The group is defined by the `partition by` clause, so rows with the same value of `PropertyId` are in the same group.

Comment: Should there be a Group By?

Comment: @Jaques . . . There should not be a `group by`.  Thank you for noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  PropertyID,
    Amount,
    (select sum(yt.Amount)
      from yourTable yt where yt.PropertyID==y.PropertyID and yt.EndDate IS NULL)
    as TotalAmount
    FROM yourTable y
    WHERE y.EndDate IS NULL
```